# Why a query on PostgreSQL (on PHP) return an array of strings instead of an assoc array?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

This is a very common operation but I do not know why I have an array of string back.

```
$res=$queryHelper->ExecuteQuery("
        SELECT (food.id,stores.name) 
        FROM food, stores 
        WHERE food.id_stores=stores.id");
```

QueryHelper Class

```
    public function ExecuteQuery($queryRec,$executeRec=array())
    {
        $sql = $this->db->prepare($queryRec);
        $sql->execute($executeRec);
        $this->res=$sql->fetchAll();
        return $this->res;
    }
```

TABLE FOOD

```
id| name  | id_stores  
0 | PASTA | 0  
1 | FISH  | 0
```

TABLE STORES

```
id  |name  
0   | MARKET0  
1   | MARKET1
```

$res is

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [row] => (0,MARKET0) ) [1] => Array ( [row] => (1,MARKET0) ) )
```

but I expect

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => (0), [1] => ["MARKET0"] ) [1] => Array ([0] => (1), [1] => ["MARKET0"] ) )
```

or something like this.
If there is only one table in the query all is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses in your SELECT:

```
SELECT (food.id,stores.name)
```

are actually constructing a ROW type so the rows that come out of your query each have a single column which contains a ROW with two values. You can think of your query producing an array of rows and you're getting something that looks like this:

```
[
    [ [ food.id, stores.name ] ],
    ...
]
```

when you're expecting:

```
[
    [ food.id, stores.name ],
    ...
]
```

The solution is to toss out the parentheses:

```
SELECT food.id,stores.name
FROM food, stores 
WHERE food.id_stores=stores.id
```

This behavior might be a little strange but it is [documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS):

> **4.2.13. Row Constructors**
>
> A row constructor is an expression that builds a row value (also called a composite value) using values for its member fields. A row constructor consists of the key word `ROW`, a left parenthesis, zero or more expressions (separated by commas) for the row field values, and finally a right parenthesis. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT ROW(1,2.5,'this is a test');
> ```
>
> **The key word `ROW` is optional when there is more than one expression in the list.**

Emphasis mine. You have two expressions in your list so `(food.id, stores.name)` and `food.id, stores.name` are different things even though `(food.id)` and `food.id` are equivalent (but `row(food.id)` would be different).